# Removing some layers in a pre-trained model in pytorch

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, pytorch

I need to use a pytorch pre-trained model but I want to remove some layers of that. This is the original model:

```
def forward_features(self, x):
    x = self.patch_embed1(x)
    x = self.pos_drop(x)
    for i, blk in enumerate(self.blocks1):
        if self.use_checkpoint and i < self.checkpoint_num[0]:
            x = checkpoint.checkpoint(blk, x)
        else:
            x = blk(x)
    x = self.patch_embed2(x)
    for i, blk in enumerate(self.blocks2):
        if self.use_checkpoint and i < self.checkpoint_num[1]:
            x = checkpoint.checkpoint(blk, x)
        else:
            x = blk(x)
    x = self.patch_embed3(x)
    for i, blk in enumerate(self.blocks3):
        if self.use_checkpoint and i < self.checkpoint_num[2]:
            x = checkpoint.checkpoint(blk, x)
        else:
            x = blk(x)
    x = self.patch_embed4(x)
    for i, blk in enumerate(self.blocks4):
        if self.use_checkpoint and i < self.checkpoint_num[3]:
            x = checkpoint.checkpoint(blk, x)
        else:
            x = blk(x)
    x = self.norm(x)
    x = self.pre_logits(x)
    return x

def forward(self, x):
    x = x[0]     #(2)
    x = self.forward_features(x)
    x = x.flatten(2).mean(-1)
    x = self.head(x)
    return x
```

I want to change the model in this manner:

```
def forward_features(self, x):
    x = self.patch_embed1(x)
    x = self.pos_drop(x)
    for i, blk in enumerate(self.blocks1):
        if self.use_checkpoint and i < self.checkpoint_num[0]:

            features1 = checkpoint.checkpoint(blk, x)
        else:
            features1 = blk(x)

    y_2 = self.patch_embed2(features1)
    for i, blk in enumerate(self.blocks2):
        if self.use_checkpoint and i < self.checkpoint_num[1]:
            features2 = checkpoint.checkpoint(blk, y_2)
        else:
            features2 = blk(y_2)
    y_3 = self.patch_embed3(features2)
    for i, blk in enumerate(self.blocks3):
        if self.use_checkpoint and i < self.checkpoint_num[2]:
            features3 = checkpoint.checkpoint(blk, y_3)
        else:
            features3 = blk(y_3)
    y_4 = self.patch_embed4(features3)
    for i, blk in enumerate(self.blocks4):
        if self.use_checkpoint and i < self.checkpoint_num[3]:
           features4 = checkpoint.checkpoint(blk, y_4)
        else:
            features4 = blk(y_4)
    
    return x, features1, features2, features3, features4

def forward(self, x):
    x, features1, features2, features3, features4 = self.forward_features(z)

    return features1, features2, features3, features4
```

How can I make these changes without having problems of mismatch between pretrained weights and the model? This is because the pytorch does not accept my modifications when it checks the similarity between model and the wrights.

Traceback of the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/code/train.py", line 370, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/user/code/train.py", line 101, in main
    model = modelName(pretrained=encoder_pretrained)
  File "/home/user/code/models/model.py", line 72, in __init__
    assert list_model_dict[i][1].shape==list_weight_dict[i][1].shape
AssertionError
```

The error is faced in the following part:

if pretrained:
print('Loading weights...')
weight_dict=torch.load(os.path.join('models','uniformer_small_k400_16x4.pth'))

```
    model_dict=self.featureExtractor.state_dict()
    
    list_model_dict=list(model_dict.items())
    list_weight_dict=list(weight_dict.items())


    
    for i in range(len(list_model_dict)):
    

        assert list_model_dict[i][1].shape==list_weight_dict[i][1].shape  # This is the line of 72
        model_dict[list_model_dict[i][0]].copy_(weight_dict[list_weight_dict[i][0]])
    
    for i in range(len(list_model_dict)):
        assert torch.all(torch.eq(model_dict[list_model_dict[i][0]],weight_dict[list_weight_dict[i][0]].to('cpu')))
    print('Loading done!')
```

Comment: Please provide the full error backtrace.

Comment: @Ivan ,Thanks for your comment  Because there are several nested codes, it is not possible to bring whole of them here but I put the main parts that causes the error to be raised . I added a part related to the error.

Comment: I understand but please provide the full error backtrace itself.

Comment: @Ivan , I added the backtrace.

Comment: But you haven't provided the relevant code ***model.py", line 72***

Comment: @Ivan , I just added it.

Comment: Your modifications of the forward functions seem irrelevant. The error occurs at the initialization stage.